# Error installing ruby gems on Ruby 2 and RVM 1.22.2

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

I'm fairly new to Ruby and RVM and Mac. I want to install ruby gems as tools for web development but I'm getting this:

```
$ gem install sass
```

Error loading RubyGems plugin "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.2.2/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": dlopen(/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.4.0/openssl.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.4.0/openssl.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.4.0/openssl.bundle (LoadError)
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    dlopen(/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.4.0/openssl.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.4.0/openssl.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.4.0/openssl.bundle
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 2):

this error could happen if libraries used to install ruby get removed, you should reinstall ruby to make it working again:

```
rvm get stable
rvm reinstall 2.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm finally able to install ruby gems.

What happened is that I installed RVM as super user. So I removed RVM as super with `rvm implode`. Restarted terminal and then installed RVM again. Gem installation works now.